# Magento 2.3 idn_to_ascii(): INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_2003 is deprecated

Tags: magento2.3, deprecated

I have Installed Fresh Magento2.3  php version 7.2.12 . When System try to send any email like order,contact,register customer etc .. .

it will through Exception and not sending any email

> main.CRITICAL: Deprecated Functionality: idn_to_ascii():
>   INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_2003 is deprecated in 
>   /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-validator/src/EmailAddress.php
>   on line 560

**error throw from here:**

```
 if (extension_loaded('intl')) {
            if (defined('INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46')) {
                return (idn_to_ascii($email, 0, INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46) ?: $email);
            }
            return (idn_to_ascii($email) ?: $email);
        }
```

Comment: Can you specify your enviroment?
mysql version.

Comment: Magento : 2.3
php         : 7.2.12
mysql      : 5.0.12

Answer (score 8):

in magento: 2.3, php: 7.2
I got same error:  Deprecated Functionality: idn_to_ascii(): INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_2003 is deprecated ..

so I downgrade php version to 7.1 then its work.
http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.deprecated.php

or another solution is to upgrade icu to ICU 4.6 http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/8.3/general/icu.html

to check icu current vesion
`uconv -V`

**INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_2003 (integer)**
Use IDNA 2003 algorithm in idn_to_utf8() and idn_to_ascii(). This is the default. This constant and using the default has been deprecated as of PHP 7.2.0.

**INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46 (integer)**
Use UTS #46 algorithm in idn_to_utf8() and idn_to_ascii(). Available as of ICU 4.6.

Answer (score 5):

For avoiding the error: Deprecated Functionality 
add error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED); 
into bootstrap.php
so email are works

Comment: its works for me php@72

Comment: I decided to use this for now as logically Zend and PHP will fix this eventually. Also, Zend itself will be deprecated by 2.4

Answer (score 2):

In my case, Magento 2.3.4 instance running on PHP 7.2.27, no changes/downgrade made in the php version.

Working for me after did the below changes into EmailAddress.php file. add the @ before idn_to_ascii

vendor/zendframework/zend-validator/src/EmailAddress.php on line 560

```
protected function idnToAscii($email)
{
    if (extension_loaded('intl')) {
        if (defined('INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46')) {
            return (idn_to_ascii($email, 0, INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46) ?: $email);
        }
        return (@idn_to_ascii($email) ?: $email);
    }
    return $email;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Magento 2.3 instance running on PHP 7.2, no changes/downgrade made in the php version.

Working for me after did the below changes into `EmailAddress.php` file.

```
vendor/zendframework/zend-validator/src/EmailAddress.php on line 560
vendor/zendframework/zend-validator/src/EmailAddress.php on line 538
```

**Function name idnToAscii**

```
protected function idnToAscii($email)
{
    if (extension_loaded('intl')) {
        if (version_compare(phpversion(), '7.2', '>')) {
        if (defined('INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46')) {
            return (idn_to_ascii($email, 0, INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46) ?: $email);
            }
        }
        return (idn_to_ascii($email) ?: $email);
    }
    return $email;
}
```

**Function name idnToUtf8**

```
protected function idnToUtf8($email)
{
    if (extension_loaded('intl')) {
        // The documentation does not clarify what kind of failure
        // can happen in idn_to_utf8. One can assume if the source
        // is not IDN encoded, it would fail, but it usually returns
        // the source string in those cases.
        // But not when the source string is long enough.
        // Thus we default to source string ourselves.
        if (version_compare(phpversion(), '7.2', '>')) {
        if (defined('INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46')) {
            return idn_to_utf8($email, 0, INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46) ?: $email;
        }
        return idn_to_utf8($email) ?: $email;
        } else {
        return idn_to_utf8($email) ?: $email;
        }
        return idn_to_utf8($email) ?: $email;
    }
    return $email;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when installing magento 2.3.5 the correct way to change the file is:

/public_html/vendor/laminas/laminas-validator/src/EmailAddress.php

on line 560

Edit the file as follows:

FROM: return idn_to_ascii ($ email)?: $ Email;
  TO: return (@idn_to_ascii ($ email)?: $ Email);

Comment: i was surprised this hadn't been fixed in 2.3.5!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error. You're probably using php7.2 or 7.3. Just downgrade to 7.1 and it'll work like a charm!

Tested!

Answer (score 0):

No need to downgrade to php 7.1 or 7.2. It worked for me just by adding below code at line 560 for the function idnToAscii($email).

```
return (@idn_to_ascii($email) ?: $email);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it works both ways

1. Either downgrade the php version to 7.1 or
2. in File vendor/zendframework/zend-validator/src/EmailAddress.php on line 560

update the line to return (@idn_to_ascii($email) ?: $email);

this worked for me in Magento ver. 2.3.3