# Mail not send from the magento2.3.1

Tags: magento2, smtp, mageplaza, mail

I am using `Magento 2.3.1` I have installed the **Mageplaza Smpt** module with its latest core module.
When I'm testing a test mail button, this error occurs.
I am using yahoo mail to send an mail.

> A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.

[image]

Comment: Please provide the corresponding entry from var/log/system.log or var/log/exception.log

Comment: This is the error in system.log **Deprecated Functionality: idn_to_ascii(): INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_2003 is deprecated in /home/linenord/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-validator/src/EmailAddress.php on line 560**

Comment: Guess you have to lower your php version. Check magento system requirements

Comment: Thanks, lot. It's now working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in magento: 2.3, php: 7.2 I got same error: Deprecated Functionality: idn_to_ascii(): INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_2003 is deprecated ..

so I downgrade php version to 7.1 then its work. http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.deprecated.php

or another solution is to upgrade icu to ICU 4.6 http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/8.3/general/icu.html

to check icu current vesion uconv -V

more refer [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/253751/magento-2-3-idn-to-ascii-intl-idna-variant-2003-is-deprecated)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It already answered by  [simonthesorcerer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/408/simonthesorcerer). Your answer also working Solutions.